# Wpf multiple tooltip staysopen property not working

Tags: wpf, tooltip

If i create just one tooltip and set it's staysopen property to false its working. But if i create multiple tooltips and set their staysopen property to false only the first tooltip i create closes after mouse click. Other ones stays open.

Why?

Sample code:

```
ToolTip tooltip = new ToolTip { Content = "Password cannot be empty." };

Password_PasswordBox.ToolTip = tooltip;
tooltip.PlacementTarget = Password_PasswordBox;
tooltip.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Top;
tooltip.IsOpen = true;
tooltip.StaysOpen = false;

ToolTip tooltip2 = new ToolTip { Content = "Username cannot be empty." };

Username_TextBox.ToolTip = tooltip2;               
tooltip2.PlacementTarget = Username_TextBox;
tooltip2.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Top;
tooltip2.IsOpen = true;
tooltip2.StaysOpen = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are forcing both tooltips to open, and then not allowing them to stay open which is causing an exception.

System.NotSupportedException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
Additional information: By default, ToolTip property does not support ToolTip element with StaysOpen set to false.

If you want them to stay open update the ToolTipService.ShowDurationProperty

```
        ToolTipService.ShowDurationProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DependencyObject), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Int32.MaxValue));

        {
            ToolTip tooltip = new ToolTip {Content = "Password cannot be empty."};

            Password_PasswordBox.ToolTip = tooltip;
            tooltip.PlacementTarget = Password_PasswordBox;
            tooltip.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Top;
            tooltip.IsOpen = true;
            //tooltip.StaysOpen = false;
        }
        {
            ToolTip tooltip2 = new ToolTip { Content = "Username cannot be empty." };

            Username_TextBox.ToolTip = tooltip2;
            tooltip2.PlacementTarget = Username_TextBox;
            tooltip2.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Top;
            tooltip2.IsOpen = true;
            //tooltip2.StaysOpen = false;
        }
```